# Why does type inference fail for lambda, but succeed for equivalent method reference?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference

I am using a lambda to implement a functional interface in the Java program below. When the lambda is passed as an argument to a generic method, the compiler flags an "incompatible types" error because it infers that the lambda implements the Func<Shape> interface, which has the compiler interpreting the lambda parameter ("thing") as being of type Shape when the lambda attempts to pass it to a method (testRound) that requires an argument of type Round. That error makes sense to me.

But the equivalent method reference does not provoke an error message. I had been under the misconception that a lambda and a method reference that could replace that lambda were interchangeable. Here, that's not so.

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        methodB(thing -> Main.testRound(thing)); // incompatible types
        methodB(Main::testRound);                // no problem here
    }

    static <T extends Shape> void methodB(Func<T> function)
    {
    }

    static boolean testRound(Round thing)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

interface Func<T>
{
    boolean test(T ob);
}

class Shape
{
}

class Round extends Shape
{
}
```

Why does the method reference succeed when the lambda fails?

**UPDATE**

Vince Emigh found the answer, which I've marked as accepted, below. While it's not part of my question, here are four ways to work around the fact that the lambda is only inferred as being of type `Func<Shape>` if one were really stuck on using lambdas:

```java
// Use a type witness.

Main.<Round>methodB(thing -> testRound(thing));

// Make the lambda's argument type explicit.

methodB((Round thing) -> testRound(thing));

// Cast the argument.

methodB(thing -> testRound((Round)thing));

// Store the lambda reference in a Func<Round> variable.

Func<Round> lambda = thing -> testRound(thing);
methodB(lambda);
```

I don't see any reason to prefer one of these over the method reference, unless one feels that lambdas are a little less dense (and, maybe, a little more readable). But, they're there if you want them.

Comment: The only assumption I can make (which I still feel is a stretch) is: *inference is occurring at different times*. With the lambda, `thing` is seen as a `T extends Shape` (inferred as soon as `thing` is declared) while `testRound` explicitly requires `Round`, causing the error. When using the method reference, the argument is seen as `Round` since it's being inferred from `Main::testRound` rather than `(T thing)`. Hope this makes sense, and keep in mind this is scepticism based on experience rather than documentation. I am looking into this in hopes for a better (more official) answer

Comment: @VinceEmigh, I had somewhat similar thoughts, with similar caveats. Please let me know if you find anything. It sure is baffling.

Comment: Maybe this: In the first invocation, the lambda implements the `Func<Shape>` interface, from which the compiler infers that the argument to the lambda is of type `Shape`, and it is a compile-time error to pass a `Shape` to `testRound`. In the second invocation, the argument type for the implementation is _copied_ from the method signature which, here, is `Round thing`. (See JLS 15.12.3, "the compile-time parameter types are the types of the formal parameters of the compile-time declaration[.]") Indeed, this means otherwise identical lambdas and member references are _not_ interchangeable.

Comment: That's pretty much what you were saying in your first comment, right @VinceEmigh?

Comment: Yes, the lambda's argument is seen as `T extends Shape`, which `T` could represent `Round`, but could also represent other types that derive from `Shape`, and there's no way for you to define the generic type arguments with a lambda. JLS mentions: "*Unlike a lambda expression, a method reference can be congruent with a generic function type (that is, a function type that has type parameters). This is because the lambda expression would need to be able to declare type parameters, and no syntax supports this; while for a method reference, no such declaration is necessary.*"

Comment: The above JLS statement is from 15.13.2, which I believe confirms our hypothesis.

Comment: Good catch! Write that up as an answer, if you want, and I'll check it as accepted. And thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JLS §15.13.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2):

> Unlike a lambda expression, a method reference can be congruent with a generic function type (that is, a function type that has type parameters). This is because the lambda expression would need to be able to declare type parameters, and no syntax supports this; while for a method reference, no such declaration is necessary.

The lambda expression raises an error since there is no type argument specified. This causes `T` to be compiled as `Shape` (as mentioned in your post), since there's nothing to help infer the argument's type.

As for method references, since the type can be inferred from the method's parameters, no explicit type argument is needed, as mentioned in the JLS statement above.