# Why does it matter if I use a method reference or a lambda here?

Tags: java, lambda, language-lawyer, javac, method-reference

When I try to compile this code

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Optional.empty().map(o -> getStringClass(o)).orElse(String.class);
    }

    static Class<?> getStringClass(Object arg) {
        return String.class;
    }

}
```

javac will fail with the following error:

```
GenericTest.java:6: error: method orElse in class Optional cannot be applied to given types;
                Optional.empty().map(o -> getStringClass(o)).orElse(String.class);
                                                            ^
  required: Class<CAP#1>
  found: Class<String>
  reason: argument mismatch; Class<String> cannot be converted to Class<CAP#1>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Optional
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

But if I use a method reference instead, javac will compile the code just fine:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class GenericTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Optional.empty().map(GenericTest::getStringClass).orElse(String.class);
    }

    static Class<?> getStringClass(Object arg) {
        return String.class;
    }

}
```

Why does it make a difference if I use a method reference or a lambda expression?

According to my understanding, both the method reference and the lambda have the type `Function<Object,Class<?>>`, so I don't see the difference here.
The eclipse java compiler (ecj) won't compile both versions by the way.

Comment: Which version of javac are you using?

Comment: Version please, it fails to compile for me in both ways. Java-8

Comment: javac 1.8.0_172 and javac 10.0.2. I know Java 10 is not recent, but I have it installed, so..

Comment: Which Java implementation do you use? Where did you get it from, Oracle?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: are you compiling this with eclipse by any chance?

Comment: The second code works fine one [ideone](https://ideone.com/k4unBs).

Answer (score 6):

This is a known [limitation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143620) of the compiler's type inference system, it doesn't work with chained method invocations like in your first code snippet.

Possible workarounds? Use an explicitly typed lambda expression:

```
Optional.empty()
        .map((Function<Object, Class<?>>) o -> getStringClass(o))
        .orElse(String.class);
```

or an exact method reference (as you've already tried):

```
Optional.empty().map(GenericTest::getStringClass).orElse(String.class);
```

or add a type witness:

```
Optional.empty().<Class<?>>map(o -> getStringClass(o)).orElse(String.class);
```

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016329/cannot-use-java-8-method-with-lambda-arguments-without-specifying-type-arguments) with a similar issue.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the first piece of code doen't work but the second does?
I know how I can avoid this kind of error, that is NOT the question. Please read the question again, and if you have an idea why it behaves differently, feel free to post an explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Method chaining strikes again. You can read [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-0.6.1/D.html) of *why* the designers of this feature found it complicated to implement (it has to do with the fact that lambda's/method references are *poly expressions* - their types are context dependent). Such a feature would require some extra burden on the compiler - and while your example would be a fairly trivial example to solve, `javac` has to care about a lot more than triviality; thus this is not yet implemented, even in java-12.

The easiest solution IMO, since this has to do with method chaining (and in your case this is possible), is not to chain:

```
Optional<Class<?>> first = Optional.empty().map(o -> getStringClass(o));
Class<?> second = first.orElse(String.class);
```

Comment: Yeah, not to chain is an appropriate solution, but I was asking why I can compile the second piece of code.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you _can't_... Either some weird javac version or you use eclipse `ecj` with an old version

Comment: @JohannesKuhn right. I don't really care what IDEA shows, at all, only what `javac` does and they indeed compile just fine, which is not what I would expect.

Comment: Yes. Yes, it compiles fine. And that is unexpected. And that's my question here, because I'm not smart enough to answer this question myself. I don't care how I can avoid this error, just "can someone explain this (for me unexpected) behavior".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814110/why-does-type-inference-fail-for-lambda-but-succeed-for-equivalent-method-refer) looks like the explanation... I will delete this answer soon, as you are correct

Answer (score 0):

As others have said it's a limitation with how type infereance works. There is some detail as to why here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2

Basically, when you use the lambda there is no type on the argument you're passing here:

```java
Optional.empty().map(o -> getStringClass(o)).orElse(String.class);
```

Since there is no type argument (and no ability to provide one) this will be an error. However with method refrences it's able to infer the type from the method parameters so it will work just fine.